# Java Regex: Match string contains any of two texts among many

Tags: java, regex

Want to match a string containing

```
(text1 or text2) and ( text3 or text4) and (text5) and (any of two among text6,text7,text8 and text9)
```

So far I have tried

```
^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5).*$
```

which matches a string contains (text1 or text2) and ( text3 or text4) and (text5) 

How to write a single pattern which fulfills my need.

**PS:**I don't want to divide the last part(any of two among text6,text7,text8 and text9) and write regex like

```
(^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5)(?=.*text6)(?=.*text7).*$)|(^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5)(?=.*text6)(?=.*text8).*$)|(^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5)(?=.*text6)(?=.*text9).*$)|(^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5)(?=.*text7)(?=.*text8).*$)|(^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5)(?=.*text7)(?=.*text9).\*$)|(^(?=.*(text1|text2))(?=.*(text3|text4))(?=.*text5)(?=.*text8)(?=.*text9).*$)
```

Since i don't know how many texts i gonna have in my last part.


Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your regex like below.

```
^(?=.*(text[12]))(?=.*(text[34]))(?=.*text5)(?=.*(text[6789]))(?=.*(?:(?!\3)text[6789])).*$
```

Java regex would be,

```
"^(?=.*(text[12]))(?=.*(text[34]))(?=.*text5)(?=.*(text[6789]))(?=.*(?:(?!\\3)text[6789])).*$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qL0fF0/2)

`(?=.*(text[6789]))(?=.*(?:(?!\3)text[6789]))` Asserts that there must be be two `text[6789]` or `text[6789]` but the text strings must not be repeated.

Comment: but text1,text2... are just examples. I may have any string in that place.

Comment: then change the above regex according to your needs, using `|` operator.

Comment: worked thanks. But still i couldn't understand the last part. Could You explain that. Why does i need (?=.*(text[6789])) in my last part?

Comment: sure but i didn't understand it yet.

Comment: You said that you want any two from text 6,7,8,9. This `(?=.*(text[6789]))` asserts that the line must have `text 6` or 7,8,9. This `text[6789]` in the lookahead was captured by the group 3. And the last `(?=.*(?:(?!\\3)text[6789]))` asserts that the line must contain any one from `text 6,7,8,9` but it must not be the one which was captured by the group 3.

Comment: You mean any one of text6,7,8 or 9

Comment: what if i doesn't know the exact group number. Is there any option to specify the group one before the current group???

Comment: i don't know how you don't know the exact group number. Groups are numbered from left to right.

Comment: because i going to form pattern from a set of words in a file through a java method. I might have a number of this kind patterns merged with a "|" in between them.

Comment: you could easily identify the group numbers. OR you could put your regex in the above demo link i provided and check for the group number at the right side.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other simpler way to do this i.e without specifying the group number?. Because doing this way cause me to count  the number of groups evertime i insert some text in my text file.

Comment: just avoid capturing groups which are present in the first two lookaheads and you must provide capturing group in the third lookahead that is `(?=.*(text[6789]))`

Comment: I didn't think of it. Thats a great idea. Thanks again.